# How to get a random IP from an IP range/subnet?

Tags: ruby, ip, subnet

Let's suppose, I have the IP Range: "52.93.50.128/32"
How can I get a random IP address that in that range?

Ruby would be preferable.

Comment: Any /32 "range" is just a single address...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [this snippet](http://#!/usr/bin/env%20ruby%20%20require%20%27ipaddr%27%20%20family%20=%20Socket::AF_INET%20%20subnet_range%20=%20IPAddr.new(%228.0.0.0/8%22,%20family).to_range%20from%20=%20subnet_range.first(2).last%20to%20=%20IPAddr.new(subnet_range.last.to_i%20-%202,%20family)%20%20puts) using [this gem](https://github.com/ruby/ipaddr) should work, the easy way is to calculate the IPs range, and then select a new

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'ipaddr'

family = Socket::AF_INET

subnet_range = IPAddr.new("52.93.50.128/32", family).to_range
from = subnet_range.first(2).last
to = IPAddr.new(subnet_range.last.to_i - 2, family)

puts "From: #{from}"
puts "To: #{to}"

random_ip = IPAddr.new(rand(from.to_i..to.to_i), family)

puts "Random IP: #{random_ip}"
```

Comment: For some reason, that always gives me '0.0.0.0'

Comment: Have you read the code? It should be immediately obvious why it doesn't work for host addresses or RFC 3021 subnets.

Comment: Also, just curious: if this doesn't answer your question, then why did you accept it as having answered your question? Having an accepted answer generally discourages people from posting other, potentially better, answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's suppose, I have the IP Range: "52.93.50.128/32" How can I get a random IP address that in that range?

That's easy. This is a host address, in other words, it isn't a range *at all*, it is just a single address. So, you just return the input again:

```ruby
def random_ip_address_from_subnet(subnet) = subnet
```

However, we can do something a little more intelligent, by taking into account the specifics of host addresses and RFC 3021 point-to-point links.

I am going to make an assumption here that you want only host addresses, and not network or broadcast addresses.

```ruby
require 'ipaddr'

def random_ip_from_subnet(subnet)
  ipaddr = IPAddr.new(subnet)
  range = host_address_range(ipaddr)
  range.to_a.sample
end

def host_address_range(subnet)
  range = subnet.to_range

  return range if rfc3021?(subnet) || host?(subnet)

  Range.new(range.begin.succ, IPAddr.new(range.end.to_i - 1, subnet.family))
end

def host?(subnet) = subnet.ipv4? && subnet.prefix == 32 || subnet.ipv6? && subnet.prefix == 128
def rfc3021?(subnet) = subnet.ipv4? && subnet.prefix == 31

require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestRandomIp < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    @subnet_address1 = '52.93.50.129/30'
    @subnet_address2 = '52.93.50.130/30'
    @subnet_address_network = '52.93.50.128/30'
    @subnet_address_broadcast = '52.93.50.131/30'
    @subnet_address1_ip = IPAddr.new(@subnet_address1).succ
    @subnet_address2_ip = @subnet_address1_ip.succ
    @subnet_address_network_ip = IPAddr.new(@subnet_address_network)
    @subnet_address_broadcast_ip = @subnet_address2_ip.succ

    @host_address = '52.93.50.128/32'
    @host_address_ip = IPAddr.new(@host_address)

    @rfc3021_address1 = '52.93.50.128/31'
    @rfc3021_address2 = '52.93.50.129/31'
    @rfc3021_address1_ip = IPAddr.new(@rfc3021_address1)
    @rfc3021_address2_ip = IPAddr.new(@rfc3021_address2).succ
  end

  def test_that_host_address_range_works_with_normal_subnet_addresses
    range1 = host_address_range(@subnet_address1_ip)
    assert_equal @subnet_address1_ip, range1.begin
    assert_equal @subnet_address2_ip, range1.end
    assert_equal @subnet_address1_ip..@subnet_address2_ip, range1
    assert_equal 2, range1.count

    range2 = host_address_range(@subnet_address2_ip)
    assert_equal @subnet_address1_ip, range2.begin
    assert_equal @subnet_address2_ip, range2.end
    assert_equal @subnet_address1_ip..@subnet_address2_ip, range2
    assert_equal 2, range2.count

    range3 = host_address_range(@subnet_address_network_ip)
    assert_equal @subnet_address1_ip, range3.begin
    assert_equal @subnet_address2_ip, range3.end
    assert_equal @subnet_address1_ip..@subnet_address2_ip, range3
    assert_equal 2, range3.count

    range4 = host_address_range(@subnet_address_broadcast_ip)
    assert_equal @subnet_address1_ip, range4.begin
    assert_equal @subnet_address2_ip, range4.end
    assert_equal @subnet_address1_ip..@subnet_address2_ip, range4
    assert_equal 2, range4.count

    assert_equal range1, range2
    assert_equal range1, range3
    assert_equal range1, range4
    assert_equal range2, range3
    assert_equal range2, range4
    assert_equal range3, range4
  end

  def test_that_host_address_range_works_with_host_addresses
    range = host_address_range(@host_address_ip)
    assert_equal @host_address_ip, range.begin
    assert_equal @host_address_ip, range.end
    assert_equal @host_address_ip..@host_address_ip, range
    assert_equal 1, range.count
  end

  def test_that_host_address_range_works_with_rfc3021_addresses
    range1 = host_address_range(@rfc3021_address1_ip)
    assert_equal @rfc3021_address1_ip, range1.begin
    assert_equal @rfc3021_address2_ip, range1.end
    assert_equal @rfc3021_address1_ip..@rfc3021_address2_ip, range1
    assert_equal 2, range1.count

    range2 = host_address_range(@rfc3021_address2_ip)
    assert_equal @rfc3021_address1_ip, range2.begin
    assert_equal @rfc3021_address2_ip, range2.end
    assert_equal @rfc3021_address1_ip..@rfc3021_address2_ip, range2
    assert_equal 2, range2.count

    assert_equal range1, range2
  end

  def test_that_random_ip_from_subnet_works_with_normal_subnet_addresses
    100.times do
      random_ip = random_ip_from_subnet(@subnet_address1)
      assert [@subnet_address1_ip, @subnet_address2_ip].include?(random_ip)
    end

    100.times do
      random_ip = random_ip_from_subnet(@subnet_address2)
      assert [@subnet_address1_ip, @subnet_address2_ip].include?(random_ip)
    end

    100.times do
      random_ip = random_ip_from_subnet(@subnet_address_network)
      assert [@subnet_address1_ip, @subnet_address2_ip].include?(random_ip)
    end

    100.times do
      random_ip = random_ip_from_subnet(@subnet_address_broadcast)
      assert [@subnet_address1_ip, @subnet_address2_ip].include?(random_ip)
    end
  end

  def test_that_random_ip_from_subnet_works_with_rfc3021_addresses
    100.times do
      random_ip = random_ip_from_subnet(@rfc3021_address1)
      assert [@rfc3021_address1_ip, @rfc3021_address2_ip].include?(random_ip)
    end

    100.times do
      random_ip = random_ip_from_subnet(@rfc3021_address2)
      assert [@rfc3021_address1_ip, @rfc3021_address2_ip].include?(random_ip)
    end
  end

  def test_that_random_ip_from_subnet_works_with_host_addresses
    100.times do
      random_ip = random_ip_from_subnet(@host_address)
      assert_equal @host_address_ip, random_ip
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would add a `mask` as parameter nevertheless, because it's common for intranets to not follow their RFC "class"

Comment: There is no such thing as a class for almost 30 years, there is no reason to worry about them at all.